# No Such Module 'Parse'/'Bolts'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, bolts-framework

I am trying to import Parse and Bolts frameworks, but the Xcode is unable to build the project. I tried following ways, but nothing seems to work out :

1. Creating groups, and copying the folder.
2. Cleaning the project and Deleting the derived data.
3. Importing the frameworks into the project and create references.

I am using Xcode 7.0 beta (swift 2.0). Screenshot of the same is attached.

[image]

Cheers and thanks in advance!![

Comment: What's in your target settings? Is the Framework linked there? You can find it under Targets -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error and I wrote in the support of the parse and they answered me that they would update for the swift 2 when Xcode 7 will get out from a beta version.

**Them answer** "We plan to support Swift 2 and Xcode 7 by the time they go out of beta. Currently, there's only one initial beta release of Xcode and iOS 9, and typically a lot of things change before Beta 3 or 4 is released. We'll be keeping a close eye on things and do a release once things settled down. We're tracking any issues reported around Swift 2 and Xcode 7: please file a bug! https://parse.com/help#report".

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue, but I was using cocoapods, as shown in parse.com docs (but they are not yet updated for XCode7 and Swift2).
I just added use_frameworks! to my Podfile

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

use_frameworks!

pod 'Bolts'
pod 'Parse'
```

Comment: I had the same issue and use_frameworks! did not work for me. I decided to go the manual way and integrated Parse using option 1 in this guide http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31420166/libsqlite3-dylib-and-libz-dylib-missing-in-xcode-7-how-do-i-use-parse (installing the frameworks manually). I then had some issues finding and linking the following 2 libraries: libz.dylib libsqlite3.dylib and solved that by clicking "Add other" and looking for the libraries in /user/lib .

Comment: I don't think adding dylib files manually is the right way. Parse documentation is not updated for XCode 7: **dylib** files are now **tbd** files! You can add these files using Build Phases > Link binary with libraries panel and selecting these files from the list, searching for libz and libsqlite (without extension). You can find quick info here about tbd files http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31450690/why-xcode-7-shows-tbd-instead-of-dylib

Comment: I see, thanks for pointing that out. I will change it in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on XCode 7 beta 6 and the 7.1

It seems that XCode does not "like" to import frameworks from a "relative" location (in this case I was importing the framework from the download folder)

I have copied the libraries in the "Frameworks" directory and imported them in the project. From there and they work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I just deleted the Parse Frameworks and added the objective-c ones with a riding-header. Now it works.