# libsqlite3.dylib and libz.dylib missing in Xcode 7. How do I use Parse?

Tags: swift, parsing, xcode7

How do I use Parse if libz.dylib and libsqlite3.dylib are missing in Xcode 7 but the .tbd version exists. I am just trying to setup Push Notifications. How do I get this to work?

Also, I think it's because of this I can't import Parse into AppDelegate.swift without an error saying it doesn't exist.

Comment: This seemed to work.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31295369/ld-framework-not-found-parse-xcode-7-beta

Answer (score 67, accepted):

As for Xcode 7 b4:
To add Parse support into existing project, follow the Parse "Set up the SDK" for existing project and to add the libz and libsqlite3 libs, use:

- Go to Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries > + > Add other
- While in the file selection window press: "<kbd>command</kbd>"+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (i.e. Go to folder) and type /usr/lib/
- From /user/lib find and add : libz.dylib and libsqlite3.dylib

Please note!: Also make sure ATS works for you - this is new in iOS9!, see more info for example at [NSURLSession "HTTP load failed kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813 ; Self signing certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791361/swift-nsurlsession-http-load-failed-kcfstreamerrordomainssl-9813-self-sign)

Comment: `libsqlite3.dylib` doesn't appear to be anywhere on my system, I'm running Xcode 7.2 on Mac OS X 10.11.3.

Answer (score 16):

In tracking down a solution to this on the mac developer forum, this seemed to be the popular answer:

> This is a known issue in the Xcode 7 beta.   To work around this issue
>   for now, please: Delete all references to .tbd files from either your
>   linked libraries phase, or from the copied bundle resources phase
>   (where they sometimes will be added). Add the library you want to link
>   manually to the "Other Linker Flags" build settings, by adding the
>   argument:
>                -l
>             for each library you want to link (for example, add "-lsqlite3" (without quotes)).   For those who are curious, the .tbd
>   files are new "text-based stub libraries", that provide a much more
>   compact version of the stub libraries for use in the SDK, and help to
>   significantly reduce its download size.

In addition to this, I found that this worked verbatim for the sqlite3 example. But for `libz.dylib` you simply need to type `-lz`

[image]

And from there I was able to build successfully on the simulator, I have yet checked on a device running iOS9

Answer (score 4):

step 1 (as described by StanislavK):

Go to Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries > + > Add other
While in the file selection window press: "CMD"+Shift+G (i.e. Go to folder) and type /usr/lib/
From /user/lib find and add : libz.dylib and libsqlite3.dylib

step 2:
open your terminal (for mac)

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/lib

sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib libsqlite3.dylib
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libz.dylib libz.dylib
```

That works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think adding dylib files manually is the right way. Parse documentation is not updated for XCode 7: .dylib files are now .tbd files! You can add these files using Build Phases > Link binary with libraries panel and selecting these files from the list, searching for libz and libsqlite3 (without the extension). You can find quick info here about tbd files : [Why Xcode 7 shows *.tbd instead of *.dylib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31450690/why-xcode-7-shows-tbd-instead-of-dylib)

Answer (score 1):

In XCode 7 the ***.dylib** files are **now *.tbd** files, just search for the library you want and change the extension to .tbd

Example:

```
libz.dylib      -> libz.tbd
libstdc++.dylib -> libstdc++.tbd
```

Thanks

Comment: In my case, `.tbd` did not work. I had to add `.dylib` from `/usr/lib`

Comment: seems fine to me so far.